# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

Tags: angular, entity-framework

I have tried many solution given here but it is not working.please help.
My component.ts is working fine and is fetching values ,no error on console but nothing is being displayed on html page.

attaching picture of html code.also writing it down

```html
<!--<app-customer-layout></app-customer-layout>-->
<div class="myContent">
  <h4>You have added the following products to the cart.</h4>
  <br />
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="border:2px solid rgba(220,230,242,1);" *ngIf="products">
      <tr style="background-color:rgba(220,230,242,1); font-size:12pt">
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th style="text-align:center" colspan="2">Action(s)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let product of products" style="background-color:white">
        <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>
        <td>{{product.Price}}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product.Quantity }}&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{product.Price * product.Quantity}}</td>
        <<!--td style="text-align:right"><button title="Update Quantity" (click)="updateCart(product)" class="btn">Update Quantity</button></td>
        <td><img title="Remove from cart" [src]="imageSrc" (click)="removeProductFromCart(product)"></td>-->
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div *ngIf="showError" style="">
      <h4 class="jumbotron" style="text-align:center;">{{errorMsg}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUvAJ.png)

Comment: Have you imported the `CommonModule` in your `app.module`

Comment: Can you attach your `app.module` file?

Comment: Try this.  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule ]
  })

Answer (score 0):

The `NgIf` directive is provided by the `CommonModule`. Please make sure `CommonModule` is imported in the module the component is in.

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
```

Comment: i have tried by importing commonmodule and browser module but still it did not work